# How to scan a barcode with livestream through webbrowser on on mobile phone in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, android, quaggajs

I'm trying to make a way to scan irl barcodes that I have printed out on paper to scan into my php website. It's only when I use the website on my phone, than I can open my phone camera and scan a barcod while he scans the barcode and sends it to my code. The code can than check my database etc.

I found a beautiful plugin to do this called [QuaggaJS](https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS), I have been playing around with it and at the moment I come further than taking a picture and let it read the barcode and the sends it to my code but I want to let it scan while I hold my camera in front of the barcode so it will close the camera out of himself. Here is an [example](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/v1.0.0-beta.1/examples/live_w_locator/)(on a desktop it would ask permission to open webcam).

In the end I want a button where I click on in my website that opens my camera so I can scan the code and when he finds a barcode he close the camera and show me the information from the product that has this barcode. Is there someone that can help me with it?

Here is some code that I used and played with. (Only works with taking picture)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/quagga.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/quagga.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    #interactive.viewport {position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;}
    #interactive.viewport > canvas, #interactive.viewport > video {max-width: 100%;width: 100%;}
    canvas.drawing, canvas.drawingBuffer {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // Create the QuaggaJS config object for the live stream
    var liveStreamConfig = {
            inputStream: {
                type : "LiveStream",
                constraints: {
                    width: {min: 640},
                    height: {min: 480},
                    aspectRatio: {min: 1, max: 100},
                    facingMode: "environment" // or "user" for the front camera
                }
            },
            locator: {
                patchSize: "medium",
                halfSample: true
            },
            numOfWorkers: (navigator.hardwareConcurrency ? navigator.hardwareConcurrency : 4),
            decoder: {
                "readers":[
                    {"format":"code_128_reader","config":{}}
                ]
            },
            locate: true
        };
    // The fallback to the file API requires a different inputStream option. 
    // The rest is the same 
    var fileConfig = $.extend(
            {}, 
            liveStreamConfig,
            {
                inputStream: {
                    size: 800
                }
            }
        );
    // Start the live stream scanner when the modal opens
    $('#livestream_scanner').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        Quagga.init(
            liveStreamConfig, 
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    $('#livestream_scanner .modal-body .error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> '+err.name+'</strong>: '+err.message+'</div>');
                    Quagga.stop();
                    return;
                }
                Quagga.start();
            }
        );
    });

    // Make sure, QuaggaJS draws frames an lines around possible 
    // barcodes on the live stream
    Quagga.onProcessed(function(result) {
        var drawingCtx = Quagga.canvas.ctx.overlay,
            drawingCanvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.overlay;

        if (result) {
            if (result.boxes) {
                drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("width")), parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("height")));
                result.boxes.filter(function (box) {
                    return box !== result.box;
                }).forEach(function (box) {
                    Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(box, {x: 0, y: 1}, drawingCtx, {color: "green", lineWidth: 2});
                });
            }

            if (result.box) {
                Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.box, {x: 0, y: 1}, drawingCtx, {color: "#00F", lineWidth: 2});
            }

            if (result.codeResult && result.codeResult.code) {
                Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.line, {x: 'x', y: 'y'}, drawingCtx, {color: 'red', lineWidth: 3});
            }
        }
    });

    // Once a barcode had been read successfully, stop quagga and 
    // close the modal after a second to let the user notice where 
    // the barcode had actually been found.
    Quagga.onDetected(function(result) {            
        if (result.codeResult.code){
            $('#scanner_input').val(result.codeResult.code);
            Quagga.stop();  
            setTimeout(function(){ $('#livestream_scanner').modal('hide'); }, 1000);            
        }
    });

    // Stop quagga in any case, when the modal is closed
    $('#livestream_scanner').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
        if (Quagga){
            Quagga.stop();  
        }
    });

    // Call Quagga.decodeSingle() for every file selected in the 
    // file input
    $("#livestream_scanner input:file").on("change", function(e) {
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length) {
            Quagga.decodeSingle($.extend({}, fileConfig, {src: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])}), function(result) {alert(result.codeResult.code);});
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="scanner_input" class="form-control" style="width:20%;" placeholder="Barcode" type="text" /> 
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#livestream_scanner"><i class="fas fa-barcode"></i> Scan</button> 

<div class="modal" id="livestream_scanner">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Barcode Scanner</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <label class="btn btn-default pull-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Use camera app
                    <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" capture="camera" class="hidden" />
                </label>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</body>
</html>
```

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me some time to get it done on myself but I found it out. I also had to get a certificate so my website is secure and allows me to use `GetUserMedia();` This is my code that I used now. With `$code = $_GET['barcode'];` I can take the variable to do other stuff with it, all up to yourself.

php code

```
<button id="opener">Barcode scanner</button>

<div id="modal" title="Barcode scanner">
    <span class="found"></span>
    <div id="interactive" class="viewport"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript/QuaggaJS

```
$(function() {
var App = {
        init : function() {
            Quagga.init(this.state, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                App.attachListeners();
                App.checkCapabilities();
                Quagga.start();
            });
        },
        checkCapabilities: function() {
            var track = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveTrack();
            var capabilities = {};
            if (typeof track.getCapabilities === 'function') {
                capabilities = track.getCapabilities();
            }
            this.applySettingsVisibility('zoom', capabilities.zoom);
            this.applySettingsVisibility('torch', capabilities.torch);
        },
        updateOptionsForMediaRange: function(node, range) {
            console.log('updateOptionsForMediaRange', node, range);
            var NUM_STEPS = 6;
            var stepSize = (range.max - range.min) / NUM_STEPS;
            var option;
            var value;
            while (node.firstChild) {
                node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i <= NUM_STEPS; i++) {
                value = range.min + (stepSize * i);
                option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = value;
                option.innerHTML = value;
                node.appendChild(option);
            }
        },
        applySettingsVisibility: function(setting, capability) {
            if (typeof capability === 'boolean') {
                var node = document.querySelector('input[name="settings_' + setting + '"]');
                if (node) {
                    node.parentNode.style.display = capability ? 'block' : 'none';
                }
                return;
            }
            if (window.MediaSettingsRange && capability instanceof window.MediaSettingsRange) {
                var node = document.querySelector('select[name="settings_' + setting + '"]');
                if (node) {
                    this.updateOptionsForMediaRange(node, capability);
                    node.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
                }
                return;
            }
        },
        initCameraSelection: function(){
            var streamLabel = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveStreamLabel();

            return Quagga.CameraAccess.enumerateVideoDevices()
            .then(function(devices) {
                function pruneText(text) {
                    return text.length > 30 ? text.substr(0, 30) : text;
                }
                var $deviceSelection = document.getElementById("deviceSelection");
                while ($deviceSelection.firstChild) {
                    $deviceSelection.removeChild($deviceSelection.firstChild);
                }
                devices.forEach(function(device) {
                    var $option = document.createElement("option");
                    $option.value = device.deviceId || device.id;
                    $option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pruneText(device.label || device.deviceId || device.id)));
                    $option.selected = streamLabel === device.label;
                    $deviceSelection.appendChild($option);
                });
            });
        },
        attachListeners: function() {
            var self = this;

            self.initCameraSelection();
            $(".controls").on("click", "button.stop", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                Quagga.stop();
            });

            $(".controls .reader-config-group").on("change", "input, select", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $target = $(e.target),
                    value = $target.attr("type") === "checkbox" ? $target.prop("checked") : $target.val(),
                    name = $target.attr("name"),
                    state = self._convertNameToState(name);

                console.log("Value of "+ state + " changed to " + value);
                self.setState(state, value);
            });
        },
        _accessByPath: function(obj, path, val) {
            var parts = path.split('.'),
                depth = parts.length,
                setter = (typeof val !== "undefined") ? true : false;

            return parts.reduce(function(o, key, i) {
                if (setter && (i + 1) === depth) {
                    if (typeof o[key] === "object" && typeof val === "object") {
                        Object.assign(o[key], val);
                    } else {
                        o[key] = val;
                    }
                }
                return key in o ? o[key] : {};
            }, obj);
        },
        _convertNameToState: function(name) {
            return name.replace("_", ".").split("-").reduce(function(result, value) {
                return result + value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.substring(1);
            });
        },
        detachListeners: function() {
            $(".controls").off("click", "button.stop");
            $(".controls .reader-config-group").off("change", "input, select");
        },
        applySetting: function(setting, value) {
            var track = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveTrack();
            if (track && typeof track.getCapabilities === 'function') {
                switch (setting) {
                case 'zoom':
                    return track.applyConstraints({advanced: [{zoom: parseFloat(value)}]});
                case 'torch':
                    return track.applyConstraints({advanced: [{torch: !!value}]});
                }
            }
        },
        setState: function(path, value) {
            var self = this;

            if (typeof self._accessByPath(self.inputMapper, path) === "function") {
                value = self._accessByPath(self.inputMapper, path)(value);
            }

            if (path.startsWith('settings.')) {
                var setting = path.substring(9);
                return self.applySetting(setting, value);
            }
            self._accessByPath(self.state, path, value);

            console.log(JSON.stringify(self.state));
            App.detachListeners();
            Quagga.stop();
            App.init();
        },
        inputMapper: {
            inputStream: {
                constraints: function(value){
                    if (/^(\d+)x(\d+)$/.test(value)) {
                        var values = value.split('x');
                        return {
                            width: {min: parseInt(values[0])},
                            height: {min: parseInt(values[1])}
                        };
                    }
                    return {
                        deviceId: value
                    };
                }
            },
            numOfWorkers: function(value) {
                return parseInt(value);
            },
            decoder: {
                readers: function(value) {
                    if (value === 'ean_extended') {
                        return [{
                            format: "ean_reader",
                            config: {
                                supplements: [
                                    'ean_5_reader', 'ean_2_reader'
                                ]
                            }
                        }];
                    }
                    return [{
                        format: value + "_reader",
                        config: {}
                    }];
                }
            }
        },
        state: {
            inputStream: {
                type : "LiveStream",
                constraints: {
                    width: {min: 640},
                    height: {min: 480},
                    aspectRatio: {min: 1, max: 100},
                    facingMode: "environment" // or user
                }
            },
            locator: {
                patchSize: "medium",
                halfSample: true
            },
            numOfWorkers: 2,
            frequency: 10,
            decoder: {
                readers : [{
                    format: "code_128_reader",
                    config: {}
                }]
            },
            locate: true
        },
        lastResult : null
    };

    App.init();



    Quagga.onDetected(function(result) {
        var code = result.codeResult.code;
        Quagga.stop();
        window.location.href="scannerview.php?barcode=" + code;
    });
});
```

Comment: FWIW, the "max: 100" parameter for aspectRatio absolutely blows things up in iOS 14.

Comment: iOS 14 didnt exist at the time

Comment: I am aware, i'm trying to stamp out any uses of that, since I'm maintaining the code now, and trying to field a lot of people suddenly having problems.  max: 2 works much better.

Comment: I am looking for something similar to this. One question about the certificate. Are you talking about https certificate? And if you need https certificate, how do you test it locally cause no https on localhost right? Thanks

Comment: You do need https certificate, I was working on this during my internship so they had these things sorted out.

Comment: Hi, I tried to QuaggaJS my web project and  I have a similar problem. My project published on iis in http in my local network; When I open the try to visual studio project as localhost, everything looks like a fine, but when I published project, so Live camera couldnt open. Should I need https ?@Ende

Comment: @hkyaaa Yes you do need https